# Página se queda congelada tras migrar servidor de correo de lotus a exchange

Tags: php, servidor

El envío de correos electrónicos tarda más tiempo y cuando son muchos puede tardar uno o dos minutos en terminar.

Mientras la página se queda en blanco y el servidor se queda completamente congelado y no se puede ir atrás ni cambiar a otro menú ni cerrar sesión, se queda siempre cargando la página como si el servidor se hubiera congelado.

Si abres otro navegador (como Firefox) el servidor responde bien.

**archivo.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set(max_execution_time, 0);
require_once "../../funciones/basededatos.php";
require_once "../../funciones/imap.php";
require_once "../../funciones/saprfc.php";
require_once "../../funciones/correo.php";

if ($HTTP_SESSION_VARS["ACCESO"] == "USUARIO") {
  echo "ACCESO DENEGADO";
  exit();
}

$ids = imap_obtener_ids();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE id IN ($ids)");
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  correo_enviar_resultados(
    $row,
    saprfc_resultado_ejecuciones($row['SAPUSER'])
  );
}
?>OK
```

¿Qué puede estar pasando? ¿por qué se queda congelado el servidor sólo en explorer?

Comment: Hola de nuevo. ¿Podrías confirmarme que te pasa en el mismo servidor PHP que la pregunta anterior? Si abres una ventana de incógnito en explorer ¿te responde bien el servidor aunque la otra ventana esté "congelada"?

Comment: si es ese, como abro una ventana de incognito?

Comment: En el menú/botón de los tres puntos `···` de la parte superior derecha del navegador pulsa en **Ventana InPrivate nueva**. ¿Sólo te pasa al enviar correos? ¿Es un formulario `<form>`? ¿Un XHR? ¿Un enlace normal `< href="...">`?

Comment: tengo rueda dentada, tengo explorer 11

Comment: es un Ajax de javascript

Comment: ¿Y si lo haces en Firefox se queda "congelado" explorer? En Firefox puedes abrir una ventana privada pulsa en "Archivo > Nueva ventana privada" o Mays + Control + P.

Comment: se congela Firefox y explorer funciona. si abro la ventana privada funciona

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme qué usas para enviar los correos y copiar/pegar el código arriba en tu pregunta? Usa el enlace "editar" que hay debajo.

Comment: Si al responderme te sale una advertencia para pasar los mensajes a un foro pulsa en ella y hablamos por allí si te viene mejor.

Comment: Es probable que estés acumulando conexiones al servidor y llegues al límite del navegador para una misma URL o algo similar, ¿está disponible online la página para probarla?

Comment: uso phpmailer, voy a poner el codigo

Comment: <?php
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set(max_execution_time, 0);
require_once("../../funciones/basededatos.php");
require_once("../../funciones/imap.php");
require_once("../../funciones/saprfc.php");
require_once("../../funciones/correo.php");

if($HTTP_SESSION_VARS["ACCESO"]=="USUARIO")
{
  echo "ACCESO DENEGADO";
  exit();
}

$ids=imap_obtener_ids();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE id IN ($ids)");
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

Comment: correo_enviar_resultados($row,saprfc_resultado_ejecuciones($row['SAPUSER']));
}
?>OK

Comment: ¿Podrías poner eso mismo en la pregunta? así puedo ver y entender mejor el código (aunque creo que sé por dónde van los tiros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a la forma en la que PHP trabaja con las variables de sesión con el gestor por defecto `files`.

En él se [bloquea exclusivamente el archivo donde se guarda la información de sesión](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_files.c#L214) durante la llamada a `session_start()` y se [desbloquea al finalizar la ejecución del script](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_files.c#L149) y guardar los cambios en las variables de sesión en el archivo en el que se guarda la información de sesión, por lo que no es posible ejecutar de manera concurrente dos o más archivos PHP que pertenezcan a la misma sesión, se quedarían esperando que el archivo finalice el bloqueo.

Por ese motivo, mientras dure la ejecución de ese script PHP tan largo no te será posible navegar por ninguna otra página PHP usando la misma sesión.

Cuando abres otro navegador o la ventana de incógnito estás usando otra sesión diferente, por lo que ese bloqueo no se aplica (hasta que vuelvas a ejecutar un script muy largo y te ocurra lo mismo).

En principio la situación se debería solucionar sola cuando el PHP termine su trabajo, pero debido a que no impones límites de tiempo (un valor `0` indica "sin límite de tiempo") ni limitas el número de correos o controlas el tiempo transcurrido en cada iteración de tu bucle, esa incómoda situación se podría solucionar pasados muchos minutos, impacientando al usuario con una mala experiencia.

Si sólo haces uso de sólo lectura de las variables de sesión (no creas nuevas ni modificas el valor de las existentes) te recomiendo que llames [session_write_close()](http://php.net/function.session-write-close) para forzar el cierre del archivo de sesión y lo deje desbloqueado durante el resto de la (larga y pesada) ejecución del script.

Tu código pasaría a empezar así:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close(); /* Aquí desbloqueamos el archivo de sesión */
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

$fp = fopen("/tmp/bloqueo_envio_correo.txt", "w+");
/* Comprobamos que abrimos el archivo y que hemos conseguido bloqueo exclusivo */
if ($fp === false || flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) === false) {
  /* Si no lo obtenemos es porque este proceso ya se está ejecutando y aún
   no ha finalizado (aunque se mande desde otro navegador o usuario) */
  fclose($fp);
  die('Ya se están enviando los correos desde otro proceso, refresque la página para intentarlo de nuevo');
}


/* Aquí va el resto de tu código hasta el bucle final */


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  correo_enviar_resultados(
    $row,
    saprfc_resultado_ejecuciones($row['SAPUSER'])
  );
}
/* Liberamos el bloqueo */
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
?>OK
```

Con eso conseguimos que el tiempo de envío de correos u otros trabajos que realice el script no influya con un bloqueo en la carga del resto del sitio web.

PD: Ten en cuenta que esto podría provocar que un usuario impaciente pulsara de nuevo el enlace o botón de envío de correo y se repitiera el trabajo dos veces.

PD2: Con la solución usando un bloqueo de archivo podrás controlar exactamente cuándo terminó el proceso anterior, incluso aunque hayas abandonado la página, cerrado la pestaña o cerrado el navegador (el trabajo se queda haciéndose en el servidor).

PD3: En la práctica sólo es necesario que uses un control de bloqueo, o el de `fopen` con el parámetro `x` o el de `flock`, pero dejo ambos trozos de código en [mi respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/69110/4).

---

Para terminar quiero sugerirte que arregles dos posibles fuentes de problemas de seguridad que tienes en tu PHP, parecen problemas heredados de versiones muy antiguas de PHP:

- Procura evitar el uso de las funciones `mysql_*`. Migra cuando puedas el código a [PDO/mysql](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) o [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).
- La variable `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` no funciona como esperas en PHP 5.5.9 (tu versión de PHP) por lo que es probable que esté vacía cuando la uses. Deberías usar `$_SESSION` para almacenar y consultar variables de sesión.

En este último punto, a mí me genera este mensaje en el log de advertencia en el log de error de apache:

> `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: HTTP_SESSION_VARS in ...`

Pero tal y como tienes puesta la comprobación eso no importa y sigue adelante el script, así que es probable que cualquier usuario de tu aplicación sea capaz de usar ese script aunque sea del tipo "USUARIO".

Comment: ocurre lo que dices porque parece que el usuario hace dobleclick en el botón y se envía duplicados los correos ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

Comment: Un segundo edito la respuesta.

Comment: no funciona sigue enviando correos duplicados

Comment: Disculpa, no te avisé cuando terminé de editar, lo reviso y te cuento.

Comment: Por fin he reproducido tu problema correctamente. Creía que me funcionaba por cómo tenía montada mi prueba de concepto, el propio navegador ponía en "Stalled" la siguiente conexión a la misma URL, pero cambiando la URL y agregando "?<cosas aleatorias>" y he conseguido reproducir correctamente tu problema y solucionarlo.

Comment: Ya está. Había usado un parámetro en `fopen` que no creaba el archivo en caso de no existir, por lo que el `flock` y tal y como tenía montada la condición pasaba por ella siempre. He agregado dos trucos durante las últimas pruebas (que ahora ya no son necesarios) en los que uso un parámetro de creación que falla en caso de que exista previamente el archivo y, adicionalmente, lo borramos antes de soltar el bloqueo para permitir que entre el siguiente programa. PD: Con sólo uno de los sistemas valdría, dejo los dos para dejarlos documentados en la respuesta.

Comment: ahora siempre dice que ya se están enviando los correos desde otro proceso!!

Comment: ¿Has probado a borrar el archivo `/tmp/bloqueo_envio_correo.txt`?

Comment: Ya está, he modificado el código para que permita que el archivo exista previamente. Tal y como te dije en el comentario anterior no era necesario mantener ambas comprobaciones, con haber borrado el archivo hubiera sido suficiente.

Comment: gracias! ya funciona!! eres un maestro! gracias gracias y mil gracias!

Comment: Un placer ayudar :)